# Check if Expandable List first item is displaying

Tags: android, expandablelistview, visibility, listitem

I am writing an code, where I need to check if first item for Expandable List is visible.

For this I checked with [AbsListView.OnScrollListener.onScroll(..firstItem, visibleItemCount..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScroll(android.widget.AbsListView,%20int,%20int,%20int)) but it's not working exactly if list get expand.

Also is there any way to identify if first item completely visible.

Any suggestion here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution worked for me:

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if(expListView.getChildAt(firstVisibleItem) != null) { // 1
            int top = expListView.getChildAt(firstVisibleItem).getTop();

            if(top >= 0) { // 2
                if(this.firstVisibleItem != firstVisibleItem) { // 3
                    if(view != null){
                        this.firstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

1. Make sure visible-view item is not null.
2. Check move towards first displayed item. i.e. for only first item of list I am checking for, you can remove this option.
3. Discard same item request: This is important to execute else you will get multiple call.